# Why is the placeholder text not showing up in my customtkinter entry widget with Python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

The place holder text is not showing in the entry wdiget for the customtkinter.

```
def register():
global register_screen
register_screen = Toplevel(root)
register_screen.title("Register")
register_screen.geometry("300x250")
global username
global password
global username_entry
global password_entry
username = StringVar()
password = StringVar()

Label(register_screen, text="Please enter details below").pack()
Label(register_screen, text="").pack()
username_lable = Label(register_screen, text="Username")
username_lable.pack()
username_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=register_screen,textvariable=username, placeholder_text="Username")
username_entry.pack(padx=20, pady=10)
password_lable = Label(register_screen, text="Password")
password_lable.pack()
password_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=register_screen,textvariable=password, placeholder_text="Password")
password_entry.pack(padx=20, pady=10)
Label(register_screen, text="").pack()
register_button_1= customtkinter.CTkButton(master=register_screen, text="Register", command=register_user,height = 35, width = 250 )
register_button_1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.8, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)
```

[image]

Comment: Based on current design of `customtkinter.CTkEntry`, `placeholder` is disabled when `textvariable` is used.